# Dot product of two finite sequences (one of them nondecreasing)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

While reading a non-math-focused research paper I have stumbled upon the following inequality (paraphrasing in order to provide the necessary details):

Let $\left(x_i\right)_{i=0}^{N}$ denote elements of a weakly increasing finite sequence such that $x_0 \ge 1$.
Moreover, let $\left(a_i\right)_{i=0}^{N}$ be a corresponding sequence of real nonzero numbers, and assume $c \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Defining $z$ as:

$$
z=\frac{\sum_i{a_ix_i}}{\sum_i{a_i}-c}
$$

it can be shown that

$$
z > x_N \iff \sum_i{a_i} > c
$$

How can we reach this conclusion in terms of sequence $\left(a_i\right)_{i=0}^{N}$? It was presented without a formal proof, which makes me think it's trivial, but I can't seem to figure it out. On a first glance I was thinking about applying summation by parts, but we cannot say anything about partial sum of $\left(a_i\right)_{i=0}^{N}$.

I will appreciate any and all tips.

Comment: This feels off.  Say $N=1$. $a_0=3, a_1=-2,c=.5$ and $x_0=1, x_1=100$

Comment: Did you write your assumption correctly?  As it stands, the assumptions tell is that the denominator is positive, and so is $\sum a_i$.  So you could simplify things considerably by dropping the $c$ and just asking whether $\sum a_i>0\implies \sum a_ix_i>0$.  But, as my first example shows, this implication need not hold.

Comment: Is it possible that $a_i$ is supposed to be increasing too?

Comment: Thank you for feedback, I edited the question. I hope I didn't miss anything important this time.

Comment: Post edit, @lulu's sequences are still a counterexample. $z$ ends up being very negative, and you can make it more and more negative by taking a $c$ which approaches the sum of the $a_i$

Comment: The missing idea seems to be that we're checking progressively longer sub-sequences of $(x_i)$ and $(a_i)$, stopping when we find $z$ such that $x_{k+1} > z > x_k$ for some $k \le N$ (defining $x_{N+1} := \infty$). By stopping I mean ignoring any elements of both sequences not in the current sub-sequence. But I'm not sure how to write it down.